# How to get values from this JSON using Alamofire swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get values from this JSON. This is part of the JSON because the real JSON data is too long.

```
"hits" : [ {
"recipe" : {
  "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_bd8def1d09d8c308f659e6945f366271",
  "label" : "Pinchos de carne",
  "image" : "http://img.recetascomidas.com/recetas/640_480/pinchos-de-carne.jpg",
  "source" : "Recetal Comidas",
  "url" : "http://pinchos-de-carne.recetascomidas.com/",
  "shareAs" : "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/pinchos-de-carne-bd8def1d09d8c308f659e6945f366271/carne",
  "yield" : 6.0,
  "dietLabels" : [ "Low-Carb" ],
  "healthLabels" : [ "Dairy-Free", "Gluten-Free", "Egg-Free", "Peanut-Free", "Tree-Nut-Free", "Soy-Free", "Fish-Free", "Shellfish-Free" ],
  "cautions" : [ ],
  "ingredientLines" : [ "600 gr. de carne magra de cerdo", "2 cucharadas de pimentón dulce", "1 cucharada de pimentón picante", "1 cucharada de cúrcuma", "1 cucharada de sazonador especial para carnes", "3 cucharadas de perejil fresco bien picadito", "1/2 cucharada de comino", "Aceite de oliva", "3 patatas", "1 diente de ajo", "Pimienta negra", "Sal" ],
  "ingredients" : [ {
    "text" : "600 gr. de carne magra de cerdo",
    "quantity" : 600.0,
    "measure" : null,
    "food" : "carne magra cerdo",
    "weight" : 600.0
  }, {
    "text" : "2 cucharadas de pimentón dulce",
    "quantity" : 2.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "pimenton dulce",
    "weight" : 13.6
  }, {
    "text" : "1 cucharada de pimentón picante",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "pimenton picante",
    "weight" : 6.8
  }, {
    "text" : "1 cucharada de cúrcuma",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "curcuma",
    "weight" : 6.8
  }, {
    "text" : "1 cucharada de sazonador especial para carnes",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "sazonador",
    "weight" : 2.7
  }, {
    "text" : "3 cucharadas de perejil fresco bien picadito",
    "quantity" : 3.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "perejil fresco",
    "weight" : 11.4
  }, {
    "text" : "1/2 cucharada de comino",
    "quantity" : 0.5,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "comino",
    "weight" : 3.0
  }, {
    "text" : "Aceite de oliva",
    "quantity" : 2.0,
    "measure" : "tbsp",
    "food" : "aceite oliva",
    "weight" : 27.0
  }, {
    "text" : "3 patatas",
    "quantity" : 3.0,
    "measure" : null,
    "food" : "patatas",
    "weight" : 195.0
  }, {
    "text" : "1 diente de ajo",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "measure" : null,
    "food" : "ajo",
    "weight" : 3.0
  }, {
    "text" : "Pimienta negra",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "measure" : "peppercorn",
    "food" : "pimienta negra",
    "weight" : 0.3
  }, {
    "text" : "Sal",
    "quantity" : 0.0,
    "measure" : null,
    "food" : "sal",
    "weight" : 3.3346887
  } ]
```

For example, I want to get label values that is inside "recipe". I successfully print in console all the JSON, but I don't know how to get recipe values.

I hope you can help me.

This is the code I have now.

```
let url: String = "https://test-es.edamam.com/search?q=pollo"
var arregloHits: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pruebaJson()
}

func pruebaJson(){
    if ControladorService.conexionInternet(){
        ControladorService.sharedInstance.callUrlWithCompletion(url: url, params: nil, completion: { (finished, response) in
            if finished{
                let result = NSMutableArray(array: response["hits"] as! NSArray)

                self.arregloHits = result
                print(self.arregloHits)
            }else{
                print("Connection failed")
            }
        }, method: .get)
    }else{
        print("No Internet")
    }
}
```

Comment: How far does this code get? Does is successfully print the result of `print(self.arregloHits)`? Is your question now how to get each recipe from the `hits` array?

Answer (score 0):

Your top level json structure is a dictionary. So you need to parse it into [String: Any]. Then your hints level is a JSON array, so you need to parse it into [Any]

Here is an example. Don't forget to handle unwrap

```
do{
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: yourJSONData, options: []) as? [String: Any]

    let hits = json?["hits"] as? [Any]
    dump(hits)
}catch let error{

}
```